# Teamcity not DLL's for some NUnit Test projects

Tags: nunit, teamcity, filenotfoundexception

I get this error when running my Moq tests through Teamcity 5

> Test(s) failed.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException :
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Moq,
>   Version=3.1.416.3, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.    at
>   MyCode.Tests.SomeHandlerTests.Setup()

The tests run fine on my local; they just fail on the build server.

I made sure the assemblies are in the Bin (looking at them now over RDP just be double sure).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So the issue was to do with the Test DLL search path under the nunit settings

It was:

> ..\Tests\**\*Test*.dll

But is now:

> ..\Tests\*\bin\Debug\*Test*.dll

And things work nicely

**UPDATE**

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/NUnit

You can use this pattern

> **\*.dll

as long as you add this pattern in the *"Do not run tests from"* field

> **\obj\**\*.dll

Comment: Do you know why this works? I had the exact same issue, down to RDP'ing to see that it was there.

Comment: @Robert - it worked for me because originally it was also picking up the /obj/ folder, which doesn't have all the required dependencies.

Comment: Same thing happened to me and as @MickieChan said it was running the tests in the /obj folder but not sure why in my case since my pattern was %system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\\**\bin\%system.Configuration%\*.IntegrationTests.dll so not sure why it would pick up the /obj folder.  The other sign this was happening is in the build log where for each failed test it said "The test was run 2 times in the build, 1 failure".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but found that I had different version's of Moq between my 2 Test projects.

The issue that I had was that the correct version was not available.

Just do

```
Update-Package Moq
```

From the Package Manager command line